# Terraform with GCP module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform

I begin to use terraform with GCP module, I am novice in Terraform.

I donwloaded and put GCP module like "[Google VM](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm)" in my Terraform to use it.

I created main.tf file outside of google VM module, and I call this module like exemple provide in ["exemple" folder](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm/blob/master/examples/compute_instance/simple/main.tf)
I copy/paste this example in my main.tf file with var.tfvars (where I put my variables)

when I do "terraform plan" I have errors like

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable│
│   on main.tf line 31, in module "instance_template":
│   31:   project_id      = var.project_id│
│   An input variable with the name "project_id" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "project_id" {} block.
```

I think I have forget something....
Variables must be set in module and not in root module (tfvars) ?

thanks for your help

Comment: DId you define your [variable.tf file](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm/tree/master/examples/compute_instance/simple)?

Comment: Terraform has an excellent **learn** website. Invest time to learn the fundamentals.  https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform